# Limiting distribution CLT problem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2, ....$ be iid RV with mean 0, variance 1, and $E(X_i^4)$ is finite, Show that the limiting distribution of $Z_n = \sqrt{n} \frac{X_1X_2 + X_3X_4 +..... + X_{2n-1}X_{2n}}{X_1^2+X_2^2 + .... + X_{2n}^2}$ converges to N(0, 1) in distribution.

I think this problem uses CLT to prove. But I'm just stuck on where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if there are any independence assumptions. The stated property is not true in general.

Comment: With independence assumptions you can multiply and divide by $1/n$ and use both LLN and CLT.

Comment: @Michael yes, I forgot to mention the RV is iid. I try your approach by dividing 1/n , i was able to show the numerator converges to N(0,1), but for the denominator, I find it converges to 2 in probability, instead of 1. And Using Slutsky theorem, I showed that Z_n converges to N(0, 1/4) instead of N(0, 1). Not sure what I did wrong

Comment: Yes it converges in distribution to $N(0, 1/4)$.